# Populate Column Data based on source table in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I'm not sure my question is even worded correctly but here goes.

I have a table called Contacts that has FK references to tables Address, Email, Phone (*these have 1 to many with Contacts*).  I need to create a query that will pull all the data and has a column called Contact Method that shows which sub table that row came from.

```
Contact: ID, AddressID, EmailID, PhoneID
Address: ID, Line1, City, State
Email :  ID, EAddress
Phone :  ID, Number, Extension
```

I need the resulting table to look like this:

```
ContactMethod | ID | [Value1] | [Value2] | [Value3]

Address         2      N5980    Onalaska     WI
Email           8     myEmail@
Phone           5     555-5555    1234
```

Alternatively it could list all the combined columns in a row if that's simpler, I can work with that as well.  i.e.

```
ContactMethad | ID | Line1 | City | State | ID | EAddress | ID | Number | Extension
```

I looked at [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx), which is neat but doesn't seem to solve my problem by itself.  Do I need to combine it with [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Thanks for any help.

---

EDIT

My data, on table Contact would look like this:

```
ID | AddressID | PhoneID | EmailID

1      3           null      null
2     null         null      7
3     null          5        null
4     4            null      null
5     null         6         null
```

The proposed solution works except that I get 3 rows per ID.  Make sense?

Comment: Let me make a call to [bluefeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet).

Comment: In the http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ "What Have I Tried bucket": I have tried various versions using PIVOT, CASE, COALESCE.  I can post them though non have worked and I was worried it'd make my post confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *unpivot* the data using a `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES` clause to get the result:

```
select d.ContactMethod, d.id, d.Value1, d.Value2, d.Value3
from contacts c
left join address a
  on c.addressid = a.id
left join email e
  on c.emailid = e.id
left join phone p
  on c.phoneid = p.id
cross apply
(
  values
    ('Address', c.addressid, a.Line1, a.City, a.State),
    ('Email', c.emailid, e.eAddress, '', ''),
    ('Phone', c.phoneid, p.number, cast(p.extension as varchar(10)), '')
) d (ContactMethod, id, Value1, Value2, Value3)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbe50/13).

This gives the result:

```
| CONTACTMETHOD | ID |   VALUE1 |   VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|       Address |  2 |    N5980 | Onalaska |     WI |
|         Email |  8 | myEmail@ |          |        |
|         Phone |  5 | 555-5555 |     1234 |        |
```

If you want your second result, then you can use multiple joins to get it:

```
select cm.ContactMethod,
  a.id addressid,
  a.line1,
  a.city,
  a.state,
  e.id emailid,  
  e.eaddress,
  p.id phoneid,
  p.number,
  p.extension
from contacts c
cross join
(
  VALUES ('Address'),('Email'),('Phone')
) cm (ContactMethod)
left join address a
  on c.addressid = a.id
  and cm.ContactMethod = 'Address'
left join email e
  on c.emailid = e.id
  and cm.ContactMethod = 'Email'
left join phone p
  on c.phoneid = p.id
  and cm.ContactMethod = 'Phone';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbe50/26). The result is:

```
| CONTACTMETHOD | ADDRESSID |  LINE1 |     CITY |  STATE | EMAILID | EADDRESS | PHONEID |   NUMBER | EXTENSION |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       Address |         2 |  N5980 | Onalaska |     WI |  (null) |   (null) |  (null) |   (null) |    (null) |
|         Email |    (null) | (null) |   (null) | (null) |       8 | myEmail@ |  (null) |   (null) |    (null) |
|         Phone |    (null) | (null) |   (null) | (null) |  (null) |   (null) |       5 | 555-5555 |      1234 |
```

Edit #1, based on your changes you can alter the queries to the the following.

The first one with the three `value` columns, then you can just add a `WHERE` clause to filter out any `null` values:

```
select c.ID, ContactMethod, Value1, Value2, Value3
from contacts c
left join address a
  on c.addressid = a.id
left join email e
  on c.emailid = e.id
left join phone p
  on c.phoneid = p.id
cross apply
(
  values
    ('Address', c.addressid, a.Line1, a.City, a.State),
    ('Email', c.emailid, e.eAddress, null, null),
    ('Phone', c.phoneid, p.number, cast(p.extension as varchar(10)), null)
) d (ContactMethod, id, Value1, Value2, Value3)
where value1 is not null
  or value2 is not null
  or value3 is not null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2aeab/22).  The result is:

```
 ID | CONTACTMETHOD |            VALUE1 |    VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       Address |             N5980 |  Onalaska |     WI |
|  2 |         Email |          myEmail@ |    (null) | (null) |
|  3 |         Phone |          555-5555 |      1234 | (null) |
|  4 |       Address | 1417 Saint Andrew | La Crosse |     WI |
```

If you want the results in a single row, then you will want to use the `UNPIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select id,
    case col 
      when 'addressid' then 'address'
      when 'emailid' then 'email'
      when 'phoneid' then 'phone' end ContactMethod,
    contact_id
  from contacts
  unpivot
  (
    contact_id
    for col in (addressid, emailid, phoneid)
  ) unpiv
) c
left join address a
  on c.contact_id = a.id
  and c.ContactMethod = 'Address'
left join email e
  on c.contact_id = e.id
  and c.ContactMethod = 'Email'
left join phone p
  on c.contact_id = p.id
  and c.ContactMethod = 'Phone';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2aeab/5). The result of this query is:

```
| ID | CONTACTMETHOD | CONTACT_ID |             LINE1 |      CITY |  STATE | EADDRESS |   NUMBER | EXTENSION |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1 |       address |          2 |             N5980 |  Onalaska |     WI |   (null) |   (null) |    (null) |
|  2 |         email |          8 |            (null) |    (null) | (null) | myEmail@ |   (null) |    (null) |
|  3 |         phone |          5 |            (null) |    (null) | (null) |   (null) | 555-5555 |      1234 |
|  4 |       address |          3 | 1417 Saint Andrew | La Crosse |     WI |   (null) |   (null) |    (null) |
```

Comment: Awesome, never used Cross Apply before.  Follow Up question --> Do I have to list all my columns in the initial SELECT or does the initial SELECT need to match what you put in the Cross Apply e.g. `) d (ContactMethod, id, Value1, Value2, Value3)`

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Your columns that you are unpivoting are placed in the `values` clause and you will want to `select` list to contain only the final result.  Here is an example of everything being shown -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbe50/14 -- but you only want to display the new unpivoted columns. Make Sense?  :)

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks, I think I got it. I will apply it to my data and see what happens.

Comment: @bluefeet just thought of something.  On table contact there is only 1 of the 3 id's at anytime in the actual data.  When that's the case I get 3 rows per Contact.ID with what you showed me.  Is there a way to eliminate that?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin I don't understand what you are asking, can you edit your OP with data and then the desired result?

Comment: @bluefeet Sorry, just did so.  I think I can work around it in a hacky way but wondered what you thought.  Does it make sense now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26245/discussion-between-bluefeet-and-refracted-paladin)

Comment: @RefractedPaladin See my edit, with two new versions of the queries to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot easier to get to the second column layout. For that you just need to join:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Contact c
JOIN dbo.Address a
ON c.AddressID = a.ID
JOIN dbo. Email e
ON c. EmailID = e.ID
JOIN dbo. Phone p
ON c. PhoneID = p.ID
```

I just used `SELECT *`, but you will have to actually list all the columns as you do not want all of them. If you do not necessarily have a row in each child table you need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`.

For more details about JOINs checkout this series: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/

---

If you need multiple rows you can use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Contact c
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('Address','Email','Phone'))X(ContactMethod)
LEFT JOIN dbo.Address a
ON c.AddressID = a.ID
AND X.ContactMethod = 'Address'
LEFT JOIN dbo. Email e
ON c. EmailID = e.ID
AND X.ContactMethod = 'Email'
LEFT JOIN dbo. Phone p
ON c. PhoneID = p.ID
AND X.ContactMethod = 'Phone'
```

The advantage of going with the "spread out" version is that you do not have to deal with data type incompatibilities.

Comment: How do I get the column that tells me the Contact Method(i.e. What table that row came from?)?  Thanks

Comment: This will return only a single row that contains Address, EMail and Phone. Do you need them separate?

Comment: The latter query lacks one ON clause. Did you perhaps mean to **CROSS** JOIN the VALUES thing?

Comment: Yes, that was supposed to be a CROSS JOIN. I fixed it.